# Trying to extract the file name from a column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract a file name along with extension from a column in sql server table.

I have a varchar datatype column `'Input_File_Details'` with below data:

```
G:\USER_DATA\XXX\DEMOGRAPHIC\GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190409_00.txt
G:\USER_DATA\XXX\DEMOGRAPHIC\GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190511_00.txt
```

I have found below query on SO but it's giving me an error.

```
 select
     RIGHT(Input_File_Details,POSITION('/' IN REVERSE(Input_File_Details))-1) as processed_file_name 
from [dbo].[User_Interface_Details];
```

I am trying to get the file name as:

```
GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190409_00.txt
GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190511_00.txt
```

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL, String_Split might be available. i.e. `SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('G:\USER_DATA\XXX\DEMOGRAPHIC\GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190409_00.txt', '\')
where value like '%.txt'`

Comment: Thank you so much to all for such a quick response and giving variety of options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support `position()`.  Your strings seem to be very consistently formatted, so for your sample data, you can just use:

```
select right(Input_File_Details, 36)
```

If you want the value from the last `\`, then use:

```
select right(Input_File_Details, charindex('\', reverse(Input_File_Details)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
select

              RIGHT(Input_File_Details,CHARINDEX('\',  REVERSE(Input_File_Details))-1)  as processed_file_name
    from [dbo].[User_Interface_Details];
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below using `CHARINDEX()` pick last `\` position in the string then do substring

```
with cte as
(
select 'G:\USER_DATA\XXX\DEMOGRAPHIC\GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190409_00.txt' as c
union all
select 'G:\USER_DATA\XXX\DEMOGRAPHIC\GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190511_00.txt'
) select right(c, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(c))-1) from cte

file_name
GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190409_00.txt
GGIC_MNR_DEMO_EXTRACT20190511_00.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

`SELECT ss.value
FROM [User_Interface_Details] uid
CROSS APPLY string_split(uid.Input_File_Details, '\') AS ss
WHERE ss.value LIKE '%.%'`